# Renaming files to have lower case extensions with 'rename'

Tags: rename, regular-expression, perl

I'm trying to currently rename a large set of files and have been using quite kludgy methods to do so, such as:

```
rename 's:(.*)\.MOV:$1.mov:g' *.MOV
rename 's:(.*)\.JPG:$1.jpg:g' *.JPG
```

What I'd really like to do is to be able to combine all of these commands using the ['y' `sed` operator](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-49). Evidently, using this operator, you can transform items to lower case. The problem is that I need to convert only the extensions. Is there a way to do this using this command? I need to essentially transform the capture group in the following expression to lowercase: `^.+\.(.+)$`. Is there a way to do this? I'm kind of new to these kinds of transformations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's the Perl-based `rename` found on Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives, judging by the syntax. You can't use the [`tr` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr%2fSEARCHLIST%2fREPLACEMENTLIST%2fcdsr) because it acts on the whole string. But you can [match the extension](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions), and lowercase it [with `\L`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

```
rename 's/\.[^.]*$/\L$&/' *.JPG *.MOV
```

Here it's unnecessary, but if the regexp matched more than the part that you want to lowercase, you could put the part to be matched in a [group](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups):

```
rename 's/\.([^.]*)$/.\L$1/' *.JPG *.MOV
```

Replace `*.JPG *.MOV` by `*.*` to act on all files regardless of extension. In bash ≥4.3 (and also in bash 4.0–4.2, with the caveat that this also traverses symbolic links to directories), you can easily act on files in subdirectories and so on recursively:

```
rename 's/\.[^.]*$/\L$&/' **/*.*
```

For the [zsh fans](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) (the `:r` and `:e` [modifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) isolate the extension from the rest of the file):

```
autoload zmv
zmv '*.(MOV|JPG)' '${f:r}.${(L)f:e}'      # these extensions, current directory
zmv '*.*' '${f:r}.${(L)f:e}'              # all extensions, current directory
zmv '**/*.*' '${f:r}.${(L)f:e}'           # all extensions, recursive directory traversal
```

Comment: Hooray for winning!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Why not use `:r` and `:e` in zsh? They make the command simpler.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I think at the time I hadn't gotten used to `$f`, which wasn't documented. Now I've decided that I'll use `$f` anyway, and I see it's finally been added to the documentation.